# Why Laravel shows an error 'This page is'nt working', when access application without php artisan serve?

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed laravel 5.6.I can access application route with `php artisan serve`.
I want to access project with `localhost/project-name/public` but it shows an error.
[image]

I have applied different solutions describe on internet.
Like

- Rename the "server.php" file in root directory, in "index.php"
- Move your .htaccess from public folder to root directory
  but it didn't work.
  Suggest me a solution.

Comment: please provide more details, such as what are the details of the response? you can check this by opening the network tab within the dev tools of your browser

Comment: please check storage folder permission is 755

Comment: @lighter yes it is already 755

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add a virtual host to your Apache, pointing to the '/public' folder of your project.

If you are using XAMP then try this link to creating virtual host

https://medium.com/@renjithvk/install-laravel-in-xampp-virtual-host-b9974f42c9d8

Comment: i am explicitly call public directory "localhost/project-name/public".

Comment: Using Virtual hosts is ALWAYS the best idea

Comment: I want to access without virtual host, if i have to to make virtual host then i shouldn't  use php artisan serve.

Comment: yeah i know it is best solution but i want to access without virtual host also .

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Step to run laravel project without artisan**

1] move .htaccess from public/ to root directory of project for linux server

2] remove web.config from public/ folder for IIS server

3] To create proper web.config file for IIS server - ( goto IIS manager -> -> URL rewrite -> import rules -> import .htaccess from public/ -> remove red marked line if any -> apply, which will create web.config in root folder)

4] give permission to bootstrap/cache/ and storage/ for windows
rename server.php to index.php
Done

5] To access project using local virtual host or type php -S localhost:8000 in terminal , rather than http://localhost/. Other wise there will be path issue in some places as well eventually you are launching the project in server pointed by domain.